# How to set the uploaded image as the canvas background?

Tags: javascript

```
l=a.target.result;
var b=new Image();
var objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(b);
b.src=l;
document.getElementById("im_canvas").style.backgroundImage=url(objectURL);**strong text**
```

Here I am setting the uploaded image as the background of the image. But I didn't get what i wanted.

Answer (score 0):

The style in JavaScript is always `String`.

```
...style.backgroundImage = `url(${objectURL})`;
// or 'url(' + objectURL + ')'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("im_canvas").style.background='url(objectURL)';
```